# data.table performance questions : get vs [[]], in place computations

Tags: r, performance, data.table

Consider the following code snippet:

```
foo <- function(dt, num) {
    expect_equal(class(num), "numeric")
    col <- paste("b", num, sep = "_")
    col2 <- paste("b", num + 1, sep = "_")

    condition <- dt$a > 0

    st <- nanotime(Sys.time())
    dt[condition, a := a - get(col) ]
    dt[condition, a := a - get(col2) ]
    et <- nanotime(Sys.time())
    diff <- (et - st) / 1e9
    message(diff)

    st <- nanotime(Sys.time())
    tmp <- dt$a - dt[[col]]
    tmp <- tmp - dt[[col2]]
    dt[condition, a := tmp[condition]]
    et <- nanotime(Sys.time())
    diff <- (et - st) / 1e9
    message(diff)

    st <- nanotime(Sys.time())
    dt[, tmp := a - get(col)]
    dt[, tmp := a - get(col2)]
    dt[condition, a := tmp]
    et <- nanotime(Sys.time())
    diff <- (et - st) / 1e9
    message(diff)
}

dt <- data.table(c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0, g = 0, h = 0, i = 0, a = -15000:15000, b_1 = 1L, b_2 = 1L)
foo(dt, 1)
```

**Output** 
0.002342 
0.001131 
0.002389

**Queries** 
1. Is `get(col)` slower than `dt[[col]]` ? 
2. Is vectorization, howsoever complex the computation better performed over entire data, rather than subsetting ? 
3. Should a series of computations be performed outside data table and in the end set in a column rather than in place calculations ?

Answer (score 3):

If I take all of the internals and run with `microbenchmark`, it will execute each (in random order) and report some good statistics. I'll pre-compute `tmp` and `condition`,

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  a = {
    dt[condition, a := a - get(col) ]
    dt[condition, a := a - get(col2) ]
  },
  b = {
    tmp <- dt$a - dt[[col]]
    tmp <- tmp - dt[[col2]]
    dt[condition, a := tmp[condition]]
  },
  b2 = {
    tmp <- dt$a - dt[[col]]
    tmp <- tmp - dt[[col2]]
    set(dt, i = which(condition), j = "a", value = tmp[condition])
  },
  c = {
    dt[, tmp := a - get(col)]
    dt[, tmp := a - get(col2)]
    dt[condition, a := tmp]
  },
  times = 1000
)
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
#     a 2871.501 2965.951 3429.7118 3058.701 3640.551  9190.800  1000
#     b  660.601  679.701  788.5797  696.451  805.801  3675.201  1000
#    b2  166.001  176.801  251.9144  180.201  187.501 39527.302  1000
#     c 1391.001 1502.901 1633.2692 1530.150 1664.101  3638.701  1000
```

1. It appears that there is a clear winner in your original set of candidates : `dt[[col]]` outshines them all. **Edit**: however, as @jangorecki (a significant [contributor](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/DESCRIPTION#L7) to `data.table` source) commented, `data.table::set` is even faster.
2. It isn't really tested well here, but it really depends on the amount of subsetting and how "expensive" the calculations are. In this case, the calcs are rather trivial, so I would not expect much difference.
3. You're always balancing readability and maintainability with speed and efficiency. In some of my speed-sensitive stuff (length 2-4M), I tend to do everything in a raw vector, but that decision involves several factors, not just those involving `data.table`. Once you start getting into significant copies of data (R does that a lot) and many huge strengths of `data.table` (grouping, inequality joins, etc), then doing it in-table becomes much faster and, more importantly for me, more maintainable and readable.

Comment: @jangorecki How do we convert the statement `d[condition, num := num + 5]` to `set`. Do we have to `set(d, which(condition), d$num[condition] + 5)`. We would need to specify condition again and also qualify num by data table, unlike the first approac

Comment: yes, so take care to compute `condition` once, not two times. Note that you missed one `set` argument that specify column, with "num" value in your example.